# Ordering grouped sections in an iPhone UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

I have a grouped table retrieved using CoreData. The sections are based on a Boolean field in the SQLLite dB. How can I reverse the order of the groups in the table display? The default is to list the false values first (obviously, as false == 0, true == 1).

I guess I could change the database. My field name = isMandatory, so I could change it to isNotMandatory and fix my problem, but it would still be nice to know how to reverse the sort order of groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" retrieved using CoreData" is a rather broad description. If you are using a fetch request (`NSFetchRequest`), you can set the `sortDescriptors` for it. This array holds `NSSortDescriptor` instances, for which you can set the sort direction to be ascending or descending.

Comment: Thanks. Added a second sortDescriptor and that took care of my problem